# Next Js with react-xarrows gives error "ReferenceError: Element is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, next.js

I am trying to build an app where I want to display arrows connecting between components. A great project I found was [react-xarrows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xarrows), however when I am trying to use it in my code, I see an error:

> ReferenceError: Element is not defined.

[image]

Following is my `tsconfig.js`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is most likely occurring because `react-xarrows` uses the DOM API which is not available on the server during server-side rendering.

To solve that, you could dynamically import `react-xarrows` with `ssr: false` to only load it on the client-side.

```js
// Component where 'react-xarrows' is used

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Xarrow = dynamic(() => import('react-xarrows'), {
    ssr: false
});
```

Comment: I want to load on server side. suggest the changes that is required on library side. I have full control on my library.

Comment: @DheerajkumarRao That will depend on where the error comes from in your library. But generally, you'd want to only access DOM APIs inside `useEffect`s or callback functions. I would suggest looking for more generic answers to this issue or post a new detailed question for it.